# Mysql PHP: != всё равно выводит данные

Tags: php, mysql, select

Запрос

```
$sql="SELECT `id`, `title`, `url`, `parent_id`,`manufacturer_id`,`image`
          FROM `product` WHERE `disabled` != '1' AND `title` LIKE '%$query%'
          OR `content` LIKE '%$query%'
          OR `image` LIKE '%$query%'
          OR `meta_header` LIKE '%$query%'
          OR `meta_keywords` LIKE '%$query%'
          OR `meta_description` LIKE '%$query%'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Выводит также все позиции из базы со статусом disabled (int) = 1.
Подскажите, в чем проблема?

Comment: В приоритетах. Хинт: `2 + 2 * 2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql="SELECT `id`, `title`, `url`, `parent_id`,`manufacturer_id`,`image`
          FROM `product` WHERE `disabled` != '1' AND (`title` LIKE '%$query%'
          OR `content` LIKE '%$query%'
          OR `image` LIKE '%$query%'
          OR `meta_header` LIKE '%$query%'
          OR `meta_keywords` LIKE '%$query%'
          OR `meta_description` LIKE '%$query%')";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Поправил ваш запрос,нужны скобки после AND

Comment: Cлона-то я и не заметил!) Спасибо)